# How to fix the following error on Laravel Homestead VM: errno -30 rofs EROFS: read-only file system, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js'?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, homestead

When running `npm install && npm run dev` on a Homestead VM from within this directory:

`/home/vagrant/Sites/project/laravel` to install dependencies , an error appears:

```
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /home/vagrant/Sites/project/laravel/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/home/vagrant/Sites/project/laravel/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.
```

How can this error be fixed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox limits the creation of symbolic links in Shared directories in terms of security

Comment: provide more details in your answer, you answer need more explanation